# How to use protractor with appium to test both web and mobile together?

Tags: android, angularjs, protractor, appium, ui-automation

There is a web portal (a desktop website) based on AngularJS. I am using Protractor to test this web portal. The functionality is such that if some action is done on web portal the results are reflected in a mobile android app.

I need to automate this scenario, where half of the testing is done on the desktop browser using Protractor and the other half is automatically checked on the mobile app using Appium (or any other tool).

Is this possible?
If so, how?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Protractor to run your desktop tests and then also have an instance of WebdriverIO (https://webdriver.io) inside your protractor test that starts a separate Appium session.